# Rename function doesn't work, Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: function, rename

I want to rename a file with rename function:

```
rename("old_name.txt", "new_name.txt")
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the return value to see if you're getting an error code (non-zero). The response is detailed here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. That should help you pin it down.

Typically I've seen this be due to permission issues or the fact that the location is wrong. Maybe you think it is running in "c:\abc" but it is really "c:\xyz".

Comment: I am checking the return value, and is !0 and permissions are full

Comment: Glad to hear. Per the documentation link I posted, "On an error, the function returns a nonzero value and sets errno to one of the following values..." so it was encountering an error.